# How to separate individual characters from elements in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I'm working on an assignment and the problem draws a grid of squares A-J and 1-7. A function exists which randomly generates co-ordinates, e.g.

```
[['I5'],                    
['E1', 'F1', 'E2', 'F2'],
['J5', 'J6'],
['G7', 'H7']]
```

The problem to solve requires a function to read the elements in each list and draw a tile there using Turtle.

How can I separate the letter from the number in each list?

Just for testing, I'm trying to print each co-ordinate (so that I can get a better understanding, the end result actually needs to be goto(x,x) and then call a function I've already defined to draw something):

```
 for instructions in fixed_pattern_16:
        print(instructions[0][1])
```

Which outputs:

```
5
1
5
7
```

But because each list is a different length, I get a out of range error when trying to access elements that are in a position that is longer than the the length of the shortest list. E.g.:

```
print(instructions[2][0])
```

Comment: I recommend you read the meta thread on posting with questions about homework and revise your question to include some information about what you've tried so far, what you've covered in class, etc. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Since neither the alphabetic nor the numeric characters can take up more than space, and the sequence is always alpha before numeric, you could use the positions, e.g.    a='E5',    a[0] will be E, a[1] will be 5.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLavin, I'll update my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions and some nested list comprehension:

```
import re

lists = [['I5'],['E1', 'F1', 'E2', 'F2'],['J5', 'J6'],['G7', 'H7']]

### General format to unpack the list of lists
for i in lists: # Go through each list element
    for x in i: # Go through each element of the element
        print(x) # Print that element to the console

### Flattening that gives us our list comprehension,
### which we can use to unpack this list of lists
[print(x) for i in lists for x in i]

### We want to find a single alphabetic value and capture a single numeric value
### In short, \w looks for a word (letter) and \d looks for a number
### Check out https://regexr.com/ for more info and an interactive canvas.
letter_number_pat = r'\w(\d)'


### We can use re.sub(<pattern>, <replacement>, <string>) to capture and keep our
### numeric value (\1 since it is the first capture group
### Then, we'll anticipate the need to return a list of values, so we'll go with
### the traditional newline (\n) and split our results afterward
number_list = '\n'.join([re.sub(letter_number_pat, r'\1', x) for i in lists for x in i]).split('\n')
```

Input: `number_list`

Output: `['5', '1', '1', '2', '2', '5', '6', '7', '7']`

You can get unique values by calling the set() function and wrapping that in list() and sorted() functions from the standard library:

Input: `sorted(list(set(number_list)))`

Output: `['1', '2', '5', '6', '7']`